# How to evaluate sum of reciprocals of falling factorials

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How to evaluate the following sum?

$$ = \sum_{i \ge 0}^\infty \frac{i}{(a+i)^\underline{b}} $$

As an intermediate step in evaluating the sum, if we let:

$$ \Delta g(i) = \frac{1}{(a+i)^\underline{b}} $$

And assume $g(x) = 0, \forall x < 0$, is it valid to use finite calculus and say:

$$\begin{aligned}\Delta g(i) = \frac{1}{(a+i)^\underline{b}}\\
= (a+i)^\underline{-b}\end{aligned}$$

$$ g(i) = \frac{(a+i)^\underline{-b-1}}{-b}$$

Comment: This sum is equal to$$\frac1{(b-1)(b-2)(a-1)^{\underline{b-2}}}$$

Comment: How did you reach this result? To be honest, I'm not really looking for the answer, I want to understand the strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\frac{n}{(n+a)^{\underline{b}}}=f(n-1)-f(n)$$
where
$$f(n)=\frac{a+(b-1)n}{(b-1)(b-2)(n+a)^{\underline{b-1}}}$$
hence the given series is telescoping and is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{(n+a)^{\underline{b}}}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(f(n-1)-f(n))\\
&=f(-1)-\lim_{m\to\infty}f(m)\\
&=f(-1)\\
&=\frac1{(b-1)(b-2)(a-1)^{\underline{b-2}}}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks - how did you guess $f$ such that this fell out? Were you to automate,  rather than rely on intuition, this approach to solving the problem, you would need to guess an unbounded number of functions $f$. Is there a systematic way of guessing $f$?